# get data from my database table

Tags: php, symfony

I want to get data from my database table "Client",but I get this result:

```
[{},{},{}]
```

this is my code:

```
 <?php
    namespace OP\OPBundle\Controller;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use OP\OPBundle\Entity\Client;
    class ClientAPIController extends Controller
    {
        public function indexAction()
        {

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $personne = $em->getRepository('OPOPBundle:Client')->findAll();
    //    $personne_tab=array();
    //    $personne_tab['nom']=$personne->getNom();
    //    $personne_tab['prenom']=$personne->getPrenom();
    //   $personne_tab['id']=$personne->getId();
        $personntojson=  json_encode($personne);
            return $this->render('OPOPBundle:ClientAPI:index.html.twig', array(
                    'reponse'=> $personntojson
                ));    }
```

this is index.html.twig:

```
{{reponse}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple. `json_encode` will only present/convert the `public` available data. All the members in the object are probably private.

You can either :

- make the members public
- annotate your model with serialization info using [JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)
- or if you are running php > 5.4 implement the `JsonSerializable` interface and thus add a `jsonSerialize` method where you do the conversion yourself.

Comment: I see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28731801/sylius-product-bundle-configuration/28787995#28787995 but I get this error:Attempted to load class "JMSSerializerBundle" from namespace "JMS\SerializerBundle".
Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Comment: That is an all together different question. :)